# How can i create a select (dropdown List) inside the gridview on Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Im triying to create a select, for sending the selected value in an ajax later, i searched how to do it but i see mostly of cases where the select must be populated with data from the db, this is not the case. I only need the user selecting two values, i managed to create the camp at least visually

[Field inside the gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C4P6.png)

I managed to do it with this code:

```
                [
                    'attribute' => 'warehouse',
                    'label' => Yii::t('wms', 'Almacen'),
                    'vAlign' => 'middle',
                    'value' => function ($model) {
                        return Html::dropDownList('w.id', 'name', 
                        ['1' => 'Sym 1', 
                         '2' => 'Sym 2',
                        ], 
                        ['id' => 'Almacen', 'class' => 'form-control'
                    ]);
                    },
                    'format' => 'raw'
                ],
```

But at the moment of selecting it on the ajax it dont takes the value:

```
                    $(keys).each(function(i, key) {
                        var order = parseInt($('tr[data-key=' + key + ']').find('.warehouse').html());
                        units.push({
                            key: key,
                            order: warehouse,
                            value: $('#pa-'+key).val()
                        })
                    });
```

This was a fast fix, but as the way i see it y only could send data back from the gridview if i call it from the db, but i am probably wrong, kinda new to yii2 and many ways to do things here. And this is not a searchbox, is a list of items where people select on of those and send the data back

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that your dropdown is being generated correctly in the GridView. Your code looks fine for this part, but you might want to ensure that each dropdown has a unique id attribute if there are multiple rows in the GridView, right?

Try to modify the id of the dropdown to be unique for each row:

```
'value' => function ($model) {
    return Html::dropDownList('w.id', 'name', 
        ['1' => 'Sym 1', '2' => 'Sym 2'], 
        ['id' => 'Almacen-' . $model->id, 'class' => 'form-control']
    );
},
```

And you can change a little your JavaScript too, Maybe you need to adjust the selector to correctly target the dropdown.

```
$(keys).each(function(i, key) {
    var warehouse = $('#Almacen-' + key).val();
    units.push({
        key: key,
        warehouse: warehouse,
        value: $('#pa-' + key).val() // Ensure this is correct
    });
});
```

You should try to ensure your Ajax request is correctly set up to send the units array to your server. Verify that the data structure matches.

Also in the server side, try to see if that you are correctly processing the incoming data. This will depend on how your Yii2 controller action.

And use console logs in your JavaScript and debug logs in your Yii2 application to trace where the issue might be occurring.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have another doubt is there another way of generate that list? i  feel that the problems comes from the function, but i dont find another way to do it

Comment: Are you saying another way to generate on the serve-side function?